# How can I add binary image to photo gallery using objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am creating app to display image from web services on iPad
I use [FGallery](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone) to create photo gallery on my app and I retrieve binary image form web services and convert it to UIImage.

How can I add images to FGallery?

I am hoping that someone out there might have a solution that can perform this task, or if anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

FGallery is current written to load images from the application bundle or web server via URL. Because you cannot change the application bundle at run-time, you will need to change FGallery to read images from `<Application_Home>/Documents/` folder.  Once that is accomplished, you will then save your new UIImage to the application documents folder and update the `NSArray *localImages` in the `RootViewController`.